# How to camel case a compound work that looks exactly like this "HELLOWorld" to be helloWorld

Tags: java

I have the compound word HELLOWorld and I need to camel case it to be helloWorld. If I use .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase() and the convert to a camel case I have no way of knowing where the differentiate between the two words. I need to be able to use this no matter what the compound word will be. There is no consistency in the length of the two words. In all cases the first word is ALL CAPS and the second word has the first letter capitalized.

Comment: Have you tried some regex?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something before asking
Meanwhile I tried this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String oldWord= "HELLOWorld";
    int size=oldWord.length();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
         char c = oldWord.charAt(i);  
         int ascii = (int)c;
         if(!(ascii>=65 && ascii <=90))
         {
             count=i;
             break;
         }
   }
     String newWord= oldWord.substring(0, count-1);
     System.out.println(newWord.toLowerCase()+oldWord.substring(count-1,size));
}
```

N: This is not so generic

Answer (score 0):

I would try something with regex, such as:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[A-Z](?=[^A-Z])");
Matcher match = regex.matcher(yourString);
String camelCase;
if(match.find())
{
    int start = match.start();
    camelCase = yourString.substring(0, start).toLowerCase().concat(yourString.substring(start);
}
```